# how to show html tables in django rest framework instead raw data using function based views?

Tags: django-rest-framework

i want to get html tables instead of raw data by **function based views** ,
in class based views html tables and raw data appear but in function based views raw data appears only but html tables not.
so what i can do to show html tables with FBV ?

Comment: Why on earth would you do that? If you want to return html use django templates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at this https://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/html-and-forms/#rendering-html? Example is for class-based-view, but you can use it with functions

Make a decorator for renderer_classes and check what type of response should you return, `if request.accepted_renderer.format == 'html':`

P.S. I could hardly imagine, that you are not able to do this in FBV, when you already have same in classes